# Can a computer be random?

Tags: random, numbers, computer-science, theory

Just a random thought that entered my mind earlier today..

Is it possible (with the technology we have today) to have a computer (without human aid) randomly choose a number between one and ten (key word is randomly) without being based on any equations or formulas (also not being based on time/date/etc.)

Food for thought.

Comment: Yes, of course - there is a lot of hardware which rely on temperature/current/whatever fluctuations for generating random numbers.

Comment: SK-logic:  "which rely on temperature/current/whatever" falls into my statement that says: (also not being based on time/date/etc.)   (KEY word is ETC)

Comment: time and date are deterministic. dedicated crypto hardware uses non-deterministic circuit noise to produce random output and usually has a very thorough mathematic model of how many bits of true entropy it can extract from its noise sources. without dedicated hardware, there are still non-deterministic sources of entropy, which fall under your "etc" category. your question basically boils down to "is it possible to generate random numbers without doing anything".

Comment: @MadBurn - I'm not sure you understand how secure random or cryptographic hardware works. What SK-logic said is pretty much the standard on hardware-based random generation facilities. It ain't your standard .NET stuff.

Comment: @luis.espinal "without being based on any equations or formulas (also not being based on time/date/etc.)" Sorry, I didn't know cryto hardware ran on magic. My fault for being stupid.

Comment: Yeah, because a hardware based crypto hash doesn't run on equations. Right.

Answer (score 3):

Not without really specialized hardware (something like a geiger counter) that's really impractical. Computers use [pseudorandom number generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) to compensate for this. This is typically "good enough" for most purposes.

For security applications, however, [cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator#Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generators)(what a mouthful!) are required. These are still pseudorandom, but are harder to predict than simple random number generators.

Comment: That was a good read, thank you for the links.  It appears as though neither one is 100% random though, which is what I was thinking of

Comment: Carleton U: Look at @seth flowers answer on hardware RNGs, which use physical effects to generate true random numbers, like the Quantis card (http://www.idquantique.com/).

Answer (score 3):

See the wiki article on hardware generated random number generators... essentially a physical process that provides the random data, like flipping a coin, but much quicker.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator

Answer (score 0):

> choose a number between one and ten (key word is randomly) without
>   being based on any equations or formulas (also not being based on
>   time/date/etc.)

This is impossible in the strictest sense. And I assume that it is obvious to you as well.
Linux which has the best random generator uses a combination of user's keystrokes plus other variables and current time to come up with random numbers.
But this is also a form of "formula".

Comment: Neat, thanks for the input.  I had a feeling it was impossible, but thought that maybe there was a way..

Comment: What other way besides an "algoritmic" one (i.e. formula) were you expecting?

Comment: I wasn't sure, hence why I made this question. I thought that maybe there was a way that I hadn't thought of

Comment: Linux has the best random generator? Best compared to what? Also, what you describe is not a good random generator (not even close). Where did you get that it is the best random generator????? Also, it is not impossible in the strictest sense of the world. All you need is a peripheral that takes a sampling out of a natural random phenomena that is known to exhibit a uniform distribution (the key to randomness.) Then the measurement is mod'ed to whatever range and precision you need, and there you have it. You have a true random sequence bounded by the desired range.

Comment: @luis.espinal:I don't think that what you are saying is different than what I am saying. 1) What I am saying as impossible is the question on the computer coming up with a random number not based on some sort of algorithm, which is what the OP is asking.2) What you describe as `natural random phenomena` is what I also describe by user's keystrokes etc. Linux gather such statistics related to user's keystrokes, position of cursor in screen etc and produces a random number.3)I am refering to best in comparison between e.g. a statistically random and cryptographic secure generator

Comment: @user384706 - sorry, I missed the algorithmic part on the OP.